# Convert large mixed numerical and text numbers into numbers in Swift or Objective-C

Tags: swift, nsstring, nscharacterset, nsformatter

NSFormatter's `spellout` method lets you convert a word into a number. NSString's `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` lets you convert strings such as thousand into 1000. And you can pick integers out of strings using `NSCharacterSet`. However, I am struggling with how to convert a mixture of numbers and strings, for example, `about 2.4 million` or the `comes to 5 hundred` into a number.  The problem is isolating the '2.4 million' from the 'about' or other text.

Applying spellout to "2.4 million" yields 2400000. However, applying it to "about 2.4 million" gives an error.

```
extension NSString {
    public var asNum: NSNumber {
       // let stringValue = String(value: self)
        let stringValue = self
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.isLenient = true
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.number(from: stringValue as String) ?? -1
    }
}
```

How can I isolate just the terms that are part of a valid number?

Comment: Not related to your question but don't return magic numbers such as `-1`. Make the return value optional and return `nil` for invalid numbers.

Comment: Are the extra words you wish to ignore always at the start of the text? You could try to parse the string as a number. If it fails, drop the first word and try again. Keep dropping the next leading word until it works or you run out of text.

Comment: yes they usually are at beginning.  Will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a regular expression you could extract just the string with the numeric expression. Assuming that the extra words are at the beginning (as you said in a comment) you can do the following:

- Search for the numerical expression using a regular expression, in this case the expression is a number follow by one word. `\d+(\.\d+)*\s+\w+`
- Check that the expression was found `range.location != NSNotFound`
- Extract the match into a `String`

You can add just three lines to your code and it should work fine, something like this:

```
extension NSString {
    public var asNum: NSNumber {
        let stringValue = self
        let range = stringValue.range(of: #"\d+(\.\d+)*\s+\w+"#,
                                        options: .regularExpression)
        guard range.location != NSNotFound else { return -1 }
        let numberExpression = stringValue.substring(with: range)

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.isLenient = true
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.number(from: numberExpression) ?? -1
    }
}
```

If we follow @rmaaddy suggestion of returning an optional instead of the "magic number" -1 then the code looks like this:

```
extension NSString { 
    public var asNum: NSNumber? {
        let stringValue = self
        let range = stringValue.range(of: #"\d+(\.\d+)*\s+\w+"#,
                                        options: .regularExpression)
        guard range.location != NSNotFound else { return nil }
        let numberExpression = stringValue.substring(with: range)

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.isLenient = true
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.number(from: numberExpression) ?? nil
    }
}
```